# How to print/copy the output of a command on IRONPORT

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, microsoft-excel, ironport

I have to take health checks every day from ironport servers and store some information regarding the server's status at that point of time on a excel sheet.  How can I automate this process. I have been able to login to the server through a batch file.
I use Putty and connection type is SSH.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the URL `http://yourironportserver/xml/status` from the Ironport device to obtain the statistics in XML format.  This URL may need to be authenticated and/or use https, depending on your Ironport security configuration.

You can write a script to retrieve the XML using the above URL, then process it into whatever format you desire, such as CSV or XLS.  As far as I am aware, there is no third-party tool already written and generally available to do this for you, though the `check_ironport` [script for MRTG and Nagios](https://www.monitoringexchange.org/inventory/Check-Plugins/Hardware/Devices/Misc/check_ironport) may provide enough information for you to write your own.